# Laravel 4: Response::download('file.xml') renders on my browser instead of downloading on live server but works locally

Tags: php, csv, laravel-4, bluehost

I have this code on my route.php

```
Route::get('/download', function()
{
    return Response::download('file.xml');
});
```

On my local computer it downloads the xml file with options to save or view. Which is what i want, But after uploading to my server it shows the content of the xml file on the browser. Please how can I fix this? is there a configuration on the control panel that accounts for this?
I am using blue host. And if its a PDF file shows 'Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent' but everything works well on my local system.Also will not work with csv
Please how can I fix this?

Still will not work with csv file with headers

```
array('Content-Type'=>'text/csv','Content-Disposition'=>'attachment; filename="filename.csv"')
```

Comment: Try using `application/octet-stream` header instead of `text/csv` -- that might fix the issue.

Comment: That didn't work, same result. It works locally on my computer but not remotely on a live server. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a guess based on the error `Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent` message mentioned.

Your host might have different PHP error reporting settings than your local dev environment.

You potentially could be getting a NOTICE or similar error level being output before the XML file on your hosting (Perhaps due to a permissions issue where PHP can't read the file).

Check your error logs on your production server (`app/storage/logs`) to see what you can see there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was white space on the file. I simply removed the the space at the start of the file